# Change Edit Box Properties at Runtime in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

In my application I have to change Font, Font Size, Background Color properties of an Edit Box in the runtime. When the user select a particular font, color it should be updated and visible in the Edit Box. I am trying to do it by using CColorDialog , CFontDialog. Is there any efficient way of doing it??. Can I use a property bar like in the Visual Studio environment to change settings, that we used to change properties in the development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the WM_CTLCOLOR message in a class with CEdit as parent and then change the CDC object to your content.
For example :

```
HBRUSH CMyEdit::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
    HBRUSH hBrush;
    hBrush = (HBRUSH)m_myBrush; // An handle on a brush which was created with your background color for the edit
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 0, 0)); // Color for the text background
    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 255)); // Color for the text

    // More changes on the pDC like changing the font, etc...
    return hBrush;
}
```